# How to visualize 3d joints of a SMPL model based on pose params

Tags: neural-networks, data-visualization, computer-vision

I am trying to use `demo.py` in https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR. I am interested in obtaining joints from the inferred [SMPL](https://smpl.is.tue.mpg.de/) image and visualize it similar to described in README of this project: https://github.com/gulvarol/smplpytorch.

I also posted the issue here: https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR/issues/36.

#### What I tried that didn't work.

I changed https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR/blob/4e57dca4e9da305df99383ea6312e2b3de78c321/demo.py#L118 to 
`pred_vertices, pred_vertices_smpl, pred_camera, smpl_pose, smpl_shape = model(...)` to get `smpl_pose` (of shape `torch.Size([1, 24, 3, 3])`). Then I just flattened it by doing `smpl_pose.cpu().data.numpy()[:, :, :, -1].flatten('C').reshape(1, -1)` and used the resulting `(1, 72)` pose params as input in [pose_params variable of smplpytorch demo](https://github.com/gulvarol/smplpytorch/blob/a18b0197d8a7204865b2ec95307e2286533f9487/demo.py#L18).

The resulting visualization doesn't look correct to me. Is this the right approach? Perhaps there is an easier way to do what I am doing.

Also cross-posted here.

1. https://github.com/nkolot/GraphCMR/issues/36
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60667134/how-to-visualize-3d-joints-of-a-smpl-model-based-on-pose-params

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted at SO and has an upvoted answer there.